# RegisterRoutes in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I dont understand the RegisterRoutes perfectly. Lets assume the browser's current URL is

```
//Home/ListCompanies/{filter}
http://localhost:21047/Home/ListProducers/Yerli
```

we came to the address above with the link below

```
@Html.ActionLink("Yerli Markalar", "ListProducers/Yerli", "Home")
```

And I have a link on the current page like below

```
@Html.ActionLink("Bayiler", "ListCompanies", "Home")
http://localhost:21047/Home/ListCompanies/Yerli
```

But when I hover on the last link, it displays "Yerli" filter as well which I dont give it in the link

Why does the filter "Yerli" come here? It should seem like below

```
http://localhost:21047/Home/ListCompanies/
```

What am I doing wrong?

here are my Routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Home/ListProducers/{filter}", // Route name
            new { controller = "Home", action = "ListProducers", filter = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );


 routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Home/ListCompanies/{filter}", // Route name
            new { controller = "Home", action = "ListCompanies", filter = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: Can you post the actual route?

Comment: which route? I dont understand

Comment: How are your routes defined in the code?

Comment: I added the routes, @VsevolodGoloviznin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you do not use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Yerli Markalar", "ListProducers/Yerli", "Home")
```

If "Yerli" is the parameter to be passed to

```
public ActionResult ListProducers(string filter)
```

then it needs to be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Yerli Markalar", "ListProducers", "Home", new { filter = "Yerli" }, null)
```

which will generate `..../Home/ListCompanies/Yerli`

Your problem is that you have generated the `action` parameter as `ListCompanies/Yerli` whereas it should be `ListCompanies`

Note you should also name your routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "ListProducers", // name it!
  "Home/ListProducers/{filter}", // Route name
   new { controller = "Home", action = "ListProducers", filter = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

However, those routes seem unnecessary and you could  just delete them and let the default route handle it

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and just change the method to

```
public ActionResult ListProducers(string id)
```

and use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Yerli Markalar", "ListProducers", "Home", new { id = "Yerli" }, null)
```

which will produce exactly the same result

Comment: .when I replaced the ActionLinks and MapRoutes as you said, I click the links it goes to "http://localhost:21047/Home/ListProducers?Length=4" . why does it behave like this?

Comment: I had to use it like thi "@Html.ActionLink("Yerli Markalar", "ListProducers", "Home", new { filter = "Yerli" },null)"

Comment: Yes, that's correct (will update in a moment), that overload require you to pass the html attributes as well (the last parameter)